# Is it possible to xcopy deploy a self-hosted ASP.NET Web API console application?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

According to [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api) a self-hosted ASP.NET Web API application must be run as an administrator or someone must run the `netsh http add urlacl` command on the machine that will run the application.

I have a console ASP.NET Web API application and I want the deployment procedure to be as simple as possible. Is there a way to set up the application so it can be xcopy deployed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Windows UAC restriction.  Some privileges are required if your application needs to listen on a specific port. Unless you run the application as administrator, you will have to run netsh to give permissions to the windows account running the app to open the port. You can add a manifest to the console application to force it to run as administrator always.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"></requestedExecutionLevel>     
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Regards
Pablo.